# Using the result of a subquery in a CASE expression with T-SQL

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005, syntax, subquery, case

I'm writing a query with some CASE expressions and it outputs helper-data columns which help me determine whether or not a specific action is required. I would like to know if I can somehow use the result of a subquery as the output without having to perform the same query twice (between `WHEN (subquery) THEN` and as the result after `THEN`)

The dummy code below describes what I'm after. Can this be done? I'm querying a MS2005 SQL database.

```
SELECT   'Hello StackOverflow'
        ,'Thanks for reading this question'
        ,CASE
            WHEN 
                (
                    SELECT count(*)
                    FROM    sometable
                    WHERE   condition = 1
                    AND     somethingelse = 'value'
                ) > 0 THEN
                    -- run the query again to get the number of rows
                    (
                        SELECT count(*)
                        FROM    sometable
                        WHERE   condition = 1
                        AND     somethingelse = 'value'
                    )
            ELSE 0
         END

SELECT   'Hello StackOverflow'
        ,'Thanks for reading this question'
        ,CASE
            WHEN 
                (
                    SELECT count(*)
                    FROM    sometable
                    WHERE   condition = 1
                    AND     somethingelse = 'value'
                ) AS subqry_count > 0 THEN
                    -- use the subqry_count, which fails... "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'"
                    subqry_count
            ELSE 0
         END
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether i've overlooked something important here, but if the output is either the count or 0, why not just output the count, which will be 0 in any case when there are no matching rows...?

Comment: You're completely right @MartinParkin. I was a bit stuck in the `CASE` solution because I wanted to output something like `No Action Required`. But 0 will do fine. Thanks for keeping it stupid and simple ;)

Comment: no problems - I've added an answer that will allow you to use the query in the manner you wanted as well.  Now you can do it either way :)

Comment: I've accepted your answer. Nontheless, it's fixed much easier now. Thanks again. Have a nice day

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just use the subquery as the source you are selecting from:

```
SELECT   'Hello StackOverflow'
        ,'Thanks for reading this question'
        ,CASE subqry_count.Cnt
          WHEN 0 THEN 0
          ELSE subqry_count.Cnt
        END
  FROM ( SELECT count(*) AS Cnt
                    FROM    sometable
                    WHERE   condition = 1
                    AND     somethingelse = 'value'
                )  subqry_count
```

As an aside, if you are just going to return 0 if the output from `COUNT` is 0, then you don't even need to use a `CASE` statement.